# SSTP on second NIC for backup purposes

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008, vpn, nic

We are running a couple servers, both running Windows Server 2008, the first is the remote web server which serves up HTTP through the first NIC. It has a second NIC installed and I would like to use it for dedicated backups using our internal local server over a VPN.

I have setup the VPN on the remote server but this is where my inexperience with Server 2008 comes into play. I am having trouble understanding how to getting the backup server to connect to the 2nd NIC. This will be the only machine connecting to the second NIC.

Also my boss has purchased and is wanting me to use ViceVersaPRO on the backup machine to fetch the folders from the remote machine using their VVEngine to automate it.

I seem to have everything working except getting the darn machines to connect. Even a link to a tutorial (which I did many searches for) would be helpful.

What are my best options here to accomplish this? Should I be using SSTP? I'm sure I can get my boss to use whatever is going to work best.

Comment: You're probably going to have to expand on the physical and logical network connections.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for your response. I have solved this.